# accesing a child property from interface for using it in MatTableDataSource Angular filter

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to access a value inside Interface, I can access only Person and isStudent  but not Parent filter, here is the code. I couldnt find any source about pwo-filters, when I write instead of Parent.parentName just parent, it returns me [object object] but all I need is name:

Interface

```
export interface IPerson{
  PersonId?: number;
  PersonName: string;
  description: string;
  Parent: {
    ParentId: string,
    ParentName: string,
    Parentemail: string,
    country: { id: number, name: string }
  };
  isStudent: boolean;
}
```

component

```
 templatesDataSource: MatTableDataSource<IPerson>;

 @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

displayedColumns = [
    "PersonName",
    "description",
    "Parent.ParentName",
    "isStudent",
    "edit",
    "delete",
  ];

  filters = {
    Person: new MultiValueFilter<string>("PersonName"),
    Parent: new MultiValueFilter<string>("Parent.ParentName"), //this line doesnt work
    isStudent: new MultiValueFilter<string>("isStudent"),
  };
```

HTML

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="description">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
      </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">{{ item.description }}</mat-cell>
      <mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef></mat-footer-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="Parent.ParentName">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
        <span mat-sort-header>{{ "Person.Parent" }}</span>
        <pwo-filter [filter]="filters.Parent"></pwo-filter>
      </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">
        <span>{{ item.creator.scdName }}</span>
      </mat-cell>
      <mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef></mat-footer-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="isStudent">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
        <span mat-sort-header>{{ "Person.isStudent" }}</span>
        <pwo-filter [filter]="filters.isStudent"></pwo-filter>
      </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">
        <mat-checkbox [checked]="item.isStudent" [disabled]="true">
        </mat-checkbox>
      </mat-cell>
      <mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef></mat-footer-cell>
    </ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should have been in .ts file

```
filters = {
    Person: new MultiValueFilter<string>("PersonName"),
    Parent: new MultiValueFilter<string>("Parent", (item) => item.Parent.ParentName, //this line doesnt work
    isStudent: new MultiValueFilter<string>("isStudent"),
  };
```